# Why are my Toasts not showing? The code is running but none of the toasts are showing

Tags: android

I have written a code , and its working fine but none of the toasts are showing up.

**Activity2:**

```
package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    // set the view now
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Signin);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, Activity3.class));
        }
    });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity2.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //authenticate user
            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Activity2.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                if (password.length() < 6) {
                                    inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Authentication failed, check your email and password or sign up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Activity2.this, MainActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Activity3:**

```
package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class Activity3 extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
private Button btnSignIn, btnSignUp, btnResetPassword;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private FirebaseAuth auth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_3);

    //Get Firebase auth instance
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnSignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
    btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    btnResetPassword = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

    btnResetPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
        }
    });

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.length() < 6) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //create user
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Activity3.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                            // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                            // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Activity3.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                startActivity(new Intent(Activity3.this, MainActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
}
```

**ResetPasswordActivity:**

```
package com.example.kiit.questionme2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class ResetPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText inputEmail;
private Button btnReset, btnBack;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private ProgressBar progressBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reset_password);

    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);
    btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

    btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Enter your registered email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "We have sent you instructions to reset your password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(ResetPasswordActivity.this, "Failed to send reset email!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
        }
    });
}

}
```

I have been stuck on this for quite a while now, I don't see anything wrong with the logic, but then I don't understand why are my toasts showing there is no error in the build or compiler , My lrun terminal is showing then when I am clicking on the buttons

```
"W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@35fa52d
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date.  Requires 12451000 but found 9683470"
```

But no toast is showing. None of the toasts are showing.

Comment: What are toasts?

Comment: An Android Toast is a small message displayed on the screen, similar to a tool tip or other similar popup notification. A Toast is displayed on top of the main content of an activity, and only remains visible for a short time period.

Comment: Look into the code. There so many toasts. and none of them are showing on themulator

Comment: At least mark the Toast which you expected to display
However, make sure when you call show() for a toast that this call is in the Main thread.
you can use this function to run your toast on the main thread

`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Your message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });`

Comment: Add Logs and check if you really run into these sections of code.

Comment: I did, and yes i do

Comment: check whether your if/else conditions are satisfied inside which you have written your toasts.

Answer (score 0):

Toasts are not showing because the if block isn’t executing.
Try

```
email.trim().equals(“”);
```

Because a Java String which only contains the white-space character is not considered as empty, it is considered to contain one character and its length is 1.

Comment: Did you try the equals?

Comment: Yes I did.Its the same

Answer (score 0):

Replace TextUtils.isEmpty(email) in inside if condition part by this

inputEmail.getText().isEmpty()

And do the same for password field like this

inputPassword.getText().isEmpty()

Answer (score 0):

Try with a **toast** in `oncreate`(), so that if the **toast** runs there, then the problem may be in the `return`. Don't call `return;` after the toast.